# Changing Elasticsearch document size limit

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have 2 installations of ES with version 8.3.2 and 7.17.4 . On both of them, I have seen documents of size more than 200KB not getting uploaded via logstash. If there is a size limit in ES, how and where do I change this? I have not found any such property in elasticsearch.yml .

Thanks in advance
Ajay

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there were more than 500 newlines in the files. And the multiline codec setting had 500 as a limit. Once I increased the value these files also got uploaded.

However it is strange I didnt see a WARN or ERROR log when this was happening.

Comment: The [code](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-codec-multiline/blob/34683c5e094a7faa4f6fb34bbc4ecd3c564cbe77/lib/logstash/codecs/multiline.rb#L278) does not log a message when the limit on either bytes or lines is hit. It just flushes the event to the pipeline.